# mailto: link with attachment

Tags: php, html, email, attachment, mailto

I made an app for my client that delivers a zip file with the following example structure:

```
index.html
/files/
    file.pdf  
/inc/
    style.css
```

Basically, the user will transfer the zip file onto their iPad or iPhone using an app called Sites-2-Go. At this point, they are able to open the index.html file using the iOS browser, and a page listing all the files in the zip is shown. They can click on a link, and it will open the files located in the files folder.

The reason for doing this was so the Sales people at our company could go around showing our company's products on there iPad without having to connect to the internet. It's basically an offline version of something already available online.

Anyway, my question is the following:
My boss would like to be able to click on an email link beside any of the files listed on the index.html page, and have it be attached to a new email ready to be sent.

I have been looking into the following syntax:

**`mailto:johndoe@gmail.com?subject=Test&body=Test&attachment=files/file.pdf`**

but apparently the "attachment" parameter has never actually worked due to security reasons.

I was wondering if anyone here knew of some workaround to this?

Comment: I don't have a good answe for you, but I just wanted to say this is a great idea. It's always frustrating when you're out visiting a client and you can't pick up 3G and no one ever seems to know the WiFi password for their own office. One thought- if everything that's available on the offline site is also available online, couldn't you just have the mailto link prepare an email with a link in the body of the email for the client to download the file off of your online site?

Comment: The thing is that the online site is only accessible for the staff here at the company. Even the file links themselves require authentication. I might suggest to my boss giving these clients a temporary or guest username & password. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: What if you had the link next to the item they want emailed to them open a form where they input their email address abd requested temp username/pass. Then once that form is received on your end, a dropbox could be created for that username, with the requested file(s) in it. Once the dropbox is created, have it generate an email back to the client with a link to their box where they can pick up their files.

Answer (score 2):

Why not, as Dennis suggested, link to it, but with the username and password included. You can link to them like this : protocol://username:password@URL .
If it's an FTP server the file's on, link to it like this: ftp://client001:a67b1f@nuk.eu .
If it's a HTTP server (web server) the file's on, link to it like this: http://client002:f677gj@nuk.eu . 
Safari should support this since it's a main feature of browsers. You make usernames and passwords with a .htpasswd file on apache servers (the majority). If you wanted one username & pass for every client, you could use a really long random string for the username and another the password, like: http://sch7898gdgoj0o05klfckg021167pr0n:45906igfd49ps316fyh1zagf364z@peanutbutter.org
For example:

```
mailto:johndoe@gmail.com?subject=Test&body=%3ca+href+%3d+%22http%3a%2f%2freadonlyclient%3aa7d56a8fd4h9863%40mycompany.com%22%3eDownload+File%3c%2fa%3e
```

If you're wondering, that's [URL encoded](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/urlencode/Encode.aspx).