# Android mailto: link with attachment

Tags: java, android

I face an issues with this code, somehow I cannot attach the picture to email.

```
package com.example.video.MenuItems;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.video.R;

public class Appointment extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 101;
    EditText etEmail,etSubject,etMessage;
    TextView tvAttachment;
    String email;
    String subject;
    String message;
    Uri URI = null;       

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_appointment);
        
        etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etTo);
        etSubject = findViewById(R.id.etSubject);
        etMessage = findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
        tvAttachment = findViewById(R.id.tvAttachment);
        
        Button attachment = findViewById(R.id.btAttachment);
        attachment.setOnClickListener(v -> openFolder());
        Button Sent = findViewById(R.id.btnSenTemail);
        Sent.setOnClickListener(v -> sendEmail());
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            URI = data.getData();
            tvAttachment.setText(URI.getLastPathSegment());
            tvAttachment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void sendEmail() {
        try {
            email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            subject = etSubject.getText().toString();
            message = etMessage.getText().toString();
            final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"klavia3000@gmail.com"});
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,message);

            intent.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose your Email"));

            if (URI != null) {
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);
            }
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
            this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Sending email..."));
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed try again: "+ t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void openFolder() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please [edit] your question and describe what the problem is? What happens when you run your code? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See also [ask].

Comment: There are no errors, but the pictures i choose to send its not sent, it`s sending only the text, with no attach, my question was if someone can help me in order to work. i was reading also the other topics but i don`t figuer how to make it work

Comment: I don't think you can add an attachment, [RFC 6068](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6068) does not define that option. It only mentions headers (and `body`), and that clients MUST support `subject` and `body` (only).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046100/mailto-link-with-attachment

Comment: I tried also with JavaAPI , it`s sending emails, but its not attaching anything, with the intent i managed to make it work, but i wanted to have one email address that from that one to send all emails to "example@gmail.com" and i didnt found how to make it without Intent